# The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table which is defined like this: 
[image]
Where `ProviderId` is the primary key, and `StateID` is the foreign key, that comes from another table. It is running in my laptop, therefore, it is a local database. In my table I have around 9 million entries. I know for a fact, there are duplicate entries in the table, but they are duplicate only if we compare them with a few of the fields. In order to delete the duplicate entries I ran the query found below:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
DELETE p1.*
FROM providers AS p1
JOIN (SELECT ProviderName AS PName, Address AS PAddr, StateID, Zip, MIN(ProviderId) AS PId
      FROM providers
      GROUP BY PName, PAddr, StateID, Zip
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS p2
ON p1.ProviderName = p2.PName
AND p1.Address = p2.PAddr
AND p1.StateID = p2.StateID
AND p1.Zip = p2.Zip
AND p1.ProviderId > p2.PId;
```

The point is that, it was running for about 4 and a half hours, and it showed me the error message written on the title. You can also see it : 
[image]
How can I make my query faster, and overcome the error message that I got?

Comment: Can you clarify what the query is trying to do? I understand the join but I don't understand why `p1.providerID > p2.id`? Are you trying to select all but the minimum provider id?

Comment: @McAdam331 As I have written I try to delete the duplicate entries from the table. I check whether two (or more) rows have the same values for `ProviderName`, `Address`, `StateID` and `Zip`. If they have, I want to remove all the others, and leave just one.

Comment: Okay. I don't think it's anything you can do with your query, but I found this [article](https://major.io/2010/02/16/mysql-the-total-number-of-locks-exceeds-the-lock-table-size-2/) that might help. It seems like it's solely because your table is so large. Maybe break this down into smaller increments and run 2 or 3 deletion queries?

Comment: Have you tried a `LIMIT` clause and simply run it multiple times?

Comment: @MarcusAdams Not really no. You mean to make something like `... AND p1.ProviderId > p2.PId LIMIT 0, 100000;`?

Comment: @tett I'm glad breaking down the workload helped. I wasn't sure if it would. Since it has, I've decided to add it as an answer.

Comment: I think you'd need to put the `LIMIT` clause in the `SELECT` subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [article](https://major.io/2010/02/16/mysql-the-total-number-of-locks-exceeds-the-lock-table-size-2/) I've found, it appears the problem lies in the size of your table.

The query you have will work, but I recommend breaking it down into smaller groups. For example, if your providerID ranges from 1 to 9 million (based on your question) you can just add to your where clause:

```
WHERE ProviderID <= 1000000;
```

and then run it again using 2 million, 3 million, etc. I'm not sure how small the groups have to be, that may require trial and error.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that I got your goal,

and you should better provide sqlfiddle

but you can try:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
DELETE p1
FROM providers AS p1
WHERE ProviderId NOT IN  (
      SELECT
        MIN(ProviderId) 
      FROM providers
      GROUP BY PName, PAddr, StateID, Zip
)
```

Comment: I like that approach, I didn't even think about it that way at all. This may be faster, but from is [article](https://major.io/2010/02/16/mysql-the-total-number-of-locks-exceeds-the-lock-table-size-2/) I'm not sure if the speed was the issue?

Comment: Yes, that's simpler. Though, as @McAdam331 said, also breaking down the workload helped.